# iPhone web form keypad navigation button disabled

Tags: html, css, iphone, web, mobile-safari

I have a problem with the navigation arrows on Safari on the iphone when filling in a web form.
When the form inputs initially display off the bottom of the screen when you click on the top input the arrows don't seem to work as I would expect. The arrows only navigate through the visible fields. I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour.

The buttons I'm talking about are shown below.

[image: iphone keyboard]

This is a sample html form that shows the problem on an iPhone 7 with iOS 14.7.1.
I've added some minimal styling to show the problem.

If you select the top input while the other inputs are off the bottom of the screen you can't navigate down the form using the arrow. If you scroll down first and then select one of the inputs depending on which input and where you scroll to you can sometimes navigate through the whole form.

Is there any way to get the arrows to navigate consistently through the form as it is currently displayed or is this just an iPhone "feature"? My real form is more complex than this so ideally I'd like a more generic solution - I have been able to navigate through simpler forms.

```html
<body>
<h1 style="margin: 200px 20px 200px 20px;">Heading</h1>
<form style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <label for="b3-InputAgreementnumber">Agreement number</label>
    <input required="" type="text"
        autocomplete="off" returnkeytype="next"
        keyboardtype="number-pad" id="b3-InputAgreementnumber" >
    <label for="b3-InputEmail">Email</label>
    <input required="" type="email"
        maxlength="60" autocomplete="new-password" returnkeytype="next"
        id="b3-InputEmail" >
    <label for="b3-InputConfirmationEmail">Confirm Email</label>
    <input required="" type="email"
        maxlength="60" autocomplete="new-password" returnkeytype="next"
        id="b3-InputConfirmationEmail">
    <label for="b3-InputSurname">Surname</label>
    <input required="" type="text"
        maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" returnkeytype="next"
        id="b3-InputSurname" >
    <label for="b3-InputDateofbirth">Date of birth</label>
    <input required="" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" autocomplete="off"
        returnkeytype="next" id="b3-InputDateofbirth">
    <label for="b3-InputPostcode">Enter your postcode</label>
    <input required=""
        type="text" maxlength="10" autocomplete="new-password"
        returnkeytype="next" id="b3-InputPostcode">
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Continue</button>
        <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to find a solution to this as yet but for now we've decided to disable the arrow keys on this form using a technique based on this question's answer [IOS disable the keyboard tab arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666575/ios-disable-the-keyboard-tab-arrows).

For iPhone we set all the input fields to readonly and then on focus we set the focused input to read/write using javascript.

It's not an answer but is a reasonable workaround for my use case.